# AngularJS - valueFn

Tags: javascript, oop, angularjs

What's the point of function

```
function valueFn(value) {return function() {return value;};}
```

defined in angular.js.

It's used for ex. in

```
var lowercaseFilter = valueFn(lowercase);
register('lowercase', lowercaseFilter);
```

What is different if we used lowercase directly as in

```
register('lowercase', lowercase);
```

instead of the previous line.

The same way, in the method

```
function ngDirective(directive) {
  if (isFunction(directive)) {
    directive = {
      link: directive
    }
  }
  directive.restrict = directive.restrict || 'AC';
  return valueFn(directive);
}
```

why the last line is not

```
return directive;
```

but

```
return valueFn(directive);
```

Comment: It is because functions like `register` required function to be passed as the second argument, and the function has to return the configuration object. the `valueFn` returns a function which returns the configuration object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Filters (and some other services) are regular functions, but AngularJS heavily relies on Dependency Injections so those filters (functions) are not exposed to the clients as-is (as instantiated objects), but instead are created by factory functions. This is done so AngularJS DI system can inject dependencies to a factory function (and those dependencies are available in a closure later on).

But there are cases where there is nothing to inject and the whole factory function job boils down to returning a pre-instantiated value. This is the case for the `lowercaseFilter` (and many other filters). So instead of repeating the same, almost-do-nothing factory function, the  `valueFn` was created to avoid code repetition. Without it AngularJS code would have to contain:

```
var lowercaseFilter = function(){
  return lowercase;
};
var uppercaseFilter = function(){
  return uppercase;
};
...
```

It is just more concise to write:

```
var lowercaseFilter = valueFn(lowercase);
var uppercaseFilter = valueFn(uppercase);
...
```

In short - I suspect that the reason is [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Thanks. I found http://misko.hevery.com/2010/05/29/dependency-injection-and-javascript-closures/ after your suggestion. I could call valueFn "function reference" (in terms of C++)